# Laravel hosting error 500

Tags: laravel, hosting, http-status-code-500

I have a laravel project. When I host it in a subdomain and add the file `.htaccess` to redirect to the public folder, I get the HTTP ERROR 500. First I thought that the error was from the host, but I changed the project and it worked, so the problem has to be the laravel.

my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't have any idea to resolve it.

Can any one help me?

Comment: If the page doesn't look like fency laravel error, then the only way to solve it is find apache error logs.

Comment: ok and how can i solve these errors?

Comment: Have you found them? What are they?

Comment: no, how can i found them?

Comment: try contacting your hosting support.

Answer (score 0):

I have some legacy apps running Laravel with Apache and for them this is the `.htaccess` that I use to redirect to the `public` folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```